# GAN with tensorflow: model syntax is not clear

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am very new with tensorfflow and am trying to implement [the example from the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan):

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256)  # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 1)

    return model

generator = make_generator_model()
noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100]) 
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)
```

I don't understand the syntax that consist in creating the generator with `generator = make_generator_model()` and then creating an image with `generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)`. How come the `generator` doesnt use `.fit()` in that case?

Comment: As I understood from documentation, `generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)` is only showing that you can use the generator to generate images, as it does it before trainning, the result is just noise. But the other use of `generator()` in the documentation is with `training=True`, so I didn't undestand your question

Comment: @IvoTebexreni my question is: what method or function is being called when executing `generator(noise, training=False)` ?

Comment: When you call `model_instance(input)` (in your `case generator(noise, training=False)`) you are just passing a input through your network to get the output. It's calling the method `call()`. So in this case you are just generating a Image on the output from the noise input. The `training=False` is used when you have layers that behaves differently when training (like dropout). Not sure if answers your question

Comment: In your case, the `BatchNormalization()` layer is the one that behaves differently on training and inference. https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/

Comment: So, `generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)` is not trainning your model as long is not updating any weight, just generating an image

Answer (score 0):

`generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)` is just using the generator to generate a new image on the output from noise using feedforward on the generator network. `training=False` is used to tell the network that is not a training and some layers can act differently.

`BatchNormalization` layers act differently when on training or when inferencing: https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/

Basically, in training, the input of the layer is used to define mean and variance of the data to update the layer, when inferencing, the data forwarded is not used to update, the layer normalize the data using only the mean and variance calculated when `training=True`

`generated_image = generator.predict(noise)` should have the same effect as `generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)`